# What (if any) ways are there to affect d20 rolls that are not attack rolls, ability checks, or saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e

What ways are available to the player to affect typeless d20 rolls, like the d20 for wild magic sorcerer's wild magic surge?

Comment: Related (not exactly a duplicate but I'm unsure here): "[Are there any features that help with the roll to avoid the destruction of a Wand of Fireballs when using the last charge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150448)" and "[What abilities allow me to reroll or replace die rolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140905)"

Comment: @pseudodruid Hi, what is the context that you have in mind that you would need to roll the d20 for?

Comment: @orc's plunder The context would be a Wild Magic Surge, I guess? Thats the example I gave, but I meant more in general.

Comment: I like this question and do not think it should be closed. Nearly all d20 rolls are labelled as an attack roll, ability check or saving throw, and all features I can find (e.g. a halfling's Lucky racial feature or a bard's Bardic Inspiration class feature) specifically state attack roll, ability check or saving throw. So what of d20 rolls that aren't one of those three? That's what this question is asking; seems clear to me, no need for close votes. That said, I think the answers to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150448/35259) (found by Medix2) are probably the answers to this as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### *True polymorph* into a Duergar Warlord.

The Duergar Warlord has a reaction called Scouring Instruction:

> #### Reactions
>
> ---
>
> ***Scouring Instruction.*** When an ally that the duergar can see makes a d20 roll, the duergar can roll a d6, and the ally can add the number rolled to the d20 by taking 3 (1d6) psychic damage.

A Duergar Warlord can use this reaction to affect *any* d20 roll, not just attack rolls, ability checks, and saving throws. A player character can use this feature by transforming into a Duergar Warlord via *true polymorph*, assuming the DM permits that transformation rather than permitting only a change into a generic Duergar.

Now, one might say "obviously this is a mistake, surely they will fix it!", and that may be true. However, *the wording of this feature is the same in both Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes and the more recently published Monsters of the Multiverse*. They didn't change it for *Monsters of the Multiverse*, the text where Wizards of the Coast allegedly rebalanced and reworked a lot of monster stat blocks, so it probably isn't going to change.

Answer (score 3):

There does not appear to be any way within the Rules As Written to do this, at this time.

Rolling on the Wild Magic table, or rolling when you use the last charge in a staff, (Staff of Striking/Power/etc), is very much like a player interacting with what is typically a DM rolled event. For example, a DM will typically roll on an encounter/weather/trap table in order to produce effects for the party that they are unable to influence. I would humbly suggest that these situations are formulated in a way to make them immune to player intervention.

The closest you may find would be the [Lucky feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/lucky) (PHB p. 167):

> You have 3 luck points. Whenever you make an attack roll, an ability
>   check, or a saving throw, you can spend one luck point to roll an
>   additional d20.

This is the most generic ability that allows you to "re-roll d20s" (technically roll another and then pick). It is a feat with no pre-requisites; however, it carefully stipulates Attack Roll / Ability Check / Saving Throw, which virtually all d20 rolls in 5e are.

Comment: I'll have to double check because I saw something fairly recently that said "on the next d20 roll"