# What are all of the abilities like 'Reliable Talent'?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature

In D&D 5E, the Rogue has the eponymous Reliable Talent (any roll of 9 or lower counts as 10 for skill checks you're proficient in), the Eloquence Bard has 'Silver Tongue' (similar but only for Persuasion and Deception checks using charisma). I don't think any feats grant this, but I'd consider it valid if it was 'always on'. Glibness, the 8th level spell *wouldn't count* as it's not an 'active all the time ability' and I'm only interested in things you can have active all the time.

Are there any other similar abilities granted as class/subclass abilities or feats, and if so what are they?

I'm narratively trying to find a way that a character might always be reliable at some skill, without being super-human at it.

Comment: So any class feature that sets a floor on one or more skill check?

Comment: @seriousbri ... Yeah I think that covers it.

Comment: @exempt Do you mean skill checks? If so yes, otherwise I'm not sure how the other things relate?

Comment: I assume you are looking for features that eliminate the randomness by replacing the die roll?

Comment: @exempt-medic no that's a different question for a different day

Comment: @Exempt-Medic this question would be significantly less interesting and possibly out of scope if it’s really asking “anything that adds a permanent bonus to ability checks”

Comment: @thomas sort of but I'm not sure what else that would cover? I'm less interested in say 'Barbarian's Indomitable Might' but I can't quite figure why/how to exclude that or if it's useful

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I agree but it was brought up under the answer, so I wanted to make sure

Comment: There's a question like this on the stack and I think I've answered it. Let me find it.

Comment: Related: (can't decide if one should be a duplicate or not) [abilities that reroll or replace die rolls](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140905/what-abilities-allow-me-to-reroll-or-replace-die-rolls)

Comment: @goodguy5 maybe? Sorta? It's not really focused enough for me, and misses a bunch of stuff the current answer here doesn't

Comment: Well it's 2 years old. I guess I could update it

Comment: @goodguy5 that would help, but the way this is formatted is more helpful to me. It's focused to my issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Barbarian's Indomitable Might:

> if your total for a Strength check is less than your Strength score, you can use that score in place of the total.

- Eloquence Bard's Silver Tongue

> When you make a Charisma (Persuasion) or Charisma (Deception) check, you can treat a d20 roll of 9 or lower as a 10.

- Stars Druid's Dragon Starry Form (after level 20):

> When you make an Intelligence or a Wisdom check or a Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell, you can treat a roll of 9 or lower on the d20 as a 10.

- Rogue's Reliable Talent

> Whenever you make an ability check that lets you add your proficiency bonus, you can treat a d20 roll of 9 or lower as a 10.

- Inquisitive Rogue's Ear for Deceit

> Whenever you make a Wisdom (Insight) check to determine whether a creature is lying, treat a roll of 7 or lower on the d20 as an 8.

- Chronurgy Wizard's Convergent Future (if immune to exhaustion)

> When you or a creature you can see within 60 feet of you makes an attack roll, an ability check, or a saving throw, you can use your reaction to ignore the die roll and decide whether the number rolled is the minimum needed to succeed or one less than that number (your choice).
>
> When you use this feature, you gain one level of exhaustion.

- UA Mage of Prismari's Impeccable Physicality (Druid, Sorcerer, Wizard)

> when you make a Dexterity saving throw, you can treat a d20 roll of a 9 or lower as a 10.

Comment: Maybe a technicality, but would a bards 'jack of all trades' count?

Comment: @SeriousBri I'd ask the OP, since I have *no* idea. Especially since, if it did; so would *any* class feature that grants proficiency in a skill

Comment: @SeriousBri I think we’re looking for things that set a floor to the die, eliminating randomness.

Comment: That said, maybe Portent counts?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov They *technically* raise your floor. But, yeah, I don't think that's what ASR is looking for. Also Portent can't count because it's not "active all the time"

Comment: I believe there is also the Dragon Form from the Druid, Circle of Stars: "When you make an Intelligence or a Wisdom check or a Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell, you can treat a roll of 9 or lower on the d20 as a 10." (Though it's something you turn on/off, not something permanent.)

Comment: @nben that's an honourable mention perhaps

Comment: I find it fascinating how -differently- Barbarian's version is implemented, and honestly, I like it much more.

Comment: @Daveman Of note, the OP said that *glibness* explicitly does not count